# Bash script with output

Tags: bash, scripting

I have a server that needs to send daily some files to remote machines.

I have done this script in order to automate this task.

What I need to insert on this script in order to see if this task as been successfully done?

Both tasks, the first task that sends the files and the other task that forces a reboot on that machine.

```
#!/bin/sh
    for server in `more server-list.txt`
do
   sshpass -p password scp -r /root/list/*.* root@$server:/etc/list/
done
sleep 5
for server in `more server-list.txt`
do
   sshpass -p password ssh root@$server /sbin/reboot
done
```

```
#server-list.txt
10.29.0.32 10.29.0.4 10.29.0.11 10.29.0.12 10.29.0.13 10.29.0.14
```

After I execute the following command to run the script, I only have following output

```
root@VPS:~#./sendingfiles.sh
root@VPS:~#
```

Sometimes I have a error saying that the host had timeout connection, but don't tell me which one has failed and I don't know which one as rebooted successfully

Comment: [It's not recommended to loop over lines in a file using `for`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).

Answer (score 1):

The variable '$?' stores the result of the previous command.

- 0 = success
- 1-127 = documented error
- (-128)-(-1) = OS killed the program with some signal

So perhaps:

```sh
sshpass -p password ssh root@$server /sbin/reboot
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "$server - Successfully rebooted"
else
  echo "$server - Failed to reboot"
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

1. `cat server-list.txt` not `more server-list.txt` (more is paginated)
2. If you're scripting this them it's probably easier to use a keyless password rather than going through `sshpass -p password`
3. Use `$()` instead of ` eg `for server in $(cat server-list.txt)`

Finally Some echo statements in your script

P.s. This question would be better over at SuperUser

Comment: This answer would be perfect for [codereview.se], but it doesn't answer the actual question here at all.